# One liner: creating a dictionary from list with indices as keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.x

I want to create a dictionary out of a given list, *in just one line*. The keys of the dictionary will be indices, and values will be the elements of the list. Something like this:

```
a = [51,27,13,56]         #given list

d = one-line-statement    #one line statement to create dictionary

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{0:51, 1:27, 2:13, 3:56}
```

I don't have any specific requirements as to why I want *one* line. I'm just exploring python, and wondering if that is possible.

Comment: What advantage do you think you'll gain by having this dictionary? Index lookups won't be any faster with a dictionary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, I might need, e.g, this: `{[x[0]:51, x[1]:27, x[2]:13, x[3]:56}`.

Comment: then just use `zip()`: `dict(zip(x, a))`.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

```
a = [51,27,13,56]
b = dict(enumerate(a))
print(b)
```

will produce

```
{0: 51, 1: 27, 2: 13, 3: 56}
```

> [`enumerate(sequence, start=0)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)
>
> Return an enumerate object. *sequence* must be a sequence, an *iterator*, or some other object which supports iteration. The `next()` method of the iterator returned by `enumerate()` returns a `tuple` containing a count (from *start* which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over *sequence*:

Comment: @jamylak But no need to remove yours. People could have learned about `count()`...

Answer (score 68):

With another constructor, you have

```
a = [51,27,13,56]         #given list
d={i:x for i,x in enumerate(a)}
print(d)
```

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Dict and set comprehensions were backported to Python 2.7.

Comment: I stand corrected. Still, remember that this does not apply to previous Python 2 versions.

Comment: this answer seems more generic!

Answer (score 22):

```
{x:a[x] for x in range(len(a))}
```

Answer (score 16):

Try `enumerate`: it will return a list (or iterator) of tuples `(i, a[i])`, from which you can build a `dict`:

```
a = [51,27,13,56]  
b = dict(enumerate(a))
print b
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use list comprehension.

```
a = [51,27,13,56]  
b = dict( [ (i,a[i]) for i in range(len(a)) ] )
print b
```