# Creating a list containing dictionaries whose values are sequentially selected from a different list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list of dictionaries comprised of the same key paired up with sequentially selected values from a different list.

The solutions here did not help me:
[Creating a unique list of dictionaries from a list of dictionaries which contains same keys but different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595125/creating-a-unique-list-of-dictionaries-from-a-list-of-dictionaries-which-contain),

[One liner: creating a dictionary from list with indices as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607704/one-liner-creating-a-dictionary-from-list-with-indices-as-keys/16607772),

[Create dictionary from list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929359/create-dictionary-from-list-python)

```py
ids = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
field = ['person']
container = []
```

The closest I've gotten is:

```py
for i in ids:
    container.append(dict(zip(field, [i for i in ids])))
```

Which results in:

```py
[{'person': 8}, {'person': 8}, {'person': 8}, {'person': 8}, {'person': 8}]
```

What I need:

```py
[{'person': 8}, {'person': 9}, {'person': 10}, {'person': 11}, {'person': 12}]
```

Comment: What should happen if theres more than 1 field? `{'person': 8, 'foo':8}` or `{person:8}{foo:8}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already iterating over `ids` with the `for` loop, you don't need a list comprehension as well.

And you don't need `zip`. It's not doing anything useful, because it always stops when it reaches the end of the shortest sequence. Since `field` only has one element, it just uses the first element of `[i for i in ids]`, which is why you always get `8`.

```
for i in ids:
    container.append({field[0]: i})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with `zip` if `field` only has one element, and you are already doing a list comprehension?

```
container = [{field[0]: i} for i in ids]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, if you have one field:

```
for i in ids:
    container.append(dict(zip(field, [i])))
```

for multiple field items you can do something like this:

```
from itertools import product
for i,j in product(ids, field):
    container.append(dict(zip([i],[j])))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the id's are in a sequence and continuous, (you mentioned sequentially selected values) you can use `range`, additionally if the field list has only one element, why not use the string directly.

Then this is a simple one-liner

```
print([{'person': i} for i in range(8, 13)])
#[{'person': 8}, {'person': 9}, {'person': 10}, {'person': 11}, {'person': 12}]
```

If you have multiple elements in the list, then also you will not need `zip`

```
fields = ['person', 'animal']
print([{item: i} for i in range(8, 13) for item in fields])
#[{'person': 8}, {'animal': 8}, {'person': 9}, {'animal': 9}, {'person': 10}, {'animal': 10}, {'person': 11}, {'animal': 11}, {'person': 12}, {'animal': 12}]
```

Another alternative is [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
ids = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
field = ['person']
print([{item[0]: item[1]} for item in product(field, ids)])
#[{'person': 8}, {'person': 9}, {'person': 10}, {'person': 11}, {'person': 12}]
```

```
from itertools import product
ids = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
field = ['person', 'field']
print([{item[0]: item[1]} for item in product(field, ids)])
#[{'person': 8}, {'person': 9}, {'person': 10}, {'person': 11}, {'person': 12}, {'field': 8}, {'field': 9}, {'field': 10}, {'field': 11}, {'field': 12}]
```

Comment: `range(8, 14)` goes up to 13.